# Vector application problem regarding river boat

Tags: vectors

The water in a river boat moves south at 10 mi/hr. If a motorboat is traveling due east at a speed of 20 mi/hr relative to the shore determine the speed and direction of the boat relative to the moving water.

Can someone go through this problem step by step. Initially I constructed a right triangle where 10 mi/hr and 20 mi/hr represented the legs and found the hypotenuse but I don't think that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture:

[image]

The speed relative to water is parallel to the hypotenuse. So it is:

$$\sqrt{10^2+20^2}=10\sqrt{5}$$

The angle is:

$$\arctan{\frac{10}{20}}=\arctan{\frac{1}{2}}$$

to the north from the east.

So the driver has to point the boat to that direction with speed $10\sqrt{5}$ such that the resultant direction will be straight to the east.